# (GTA V) Out of stock guns for no reason

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

PS4 Game Version 1.20, I don't know why but some guns are out of stock for no reason... can someone help? I also finished the game.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you loaded the finished game save. The guns are out of stock when you haven't progressed that far into the game to unlock them. What guns are missing ?